# How to get values from odoo context in qweb templating in odoo 9?

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I'm working in odoo 9. I have opened a wizard from JS and in that I have passed context, I want to use this context in my wizard. How can I do this?
Please see my code.

```js
     myfunc: function(e) {
     var mycontext = {};
     var is_checked = this.field_manager.get_field_value('Default')
     if (is_checked)
     {
         var model_obj = new Model('olims.ar_priority');
         var domain = [['Default', '=', true]];
         model_obj.call('search_read',[domain]).then(function(result){
         mycontext['current_priority'] = result[0]['Priority'];
         })
         alert()
         this.do_action({
                            name: ("Pop Up"),
                            res_model: 'olims.ar.priority.wizard',
                            type: 'ir.actions.act_window',
                            view_type: 'form',
                            view_mode: 'form',
                            views: [
                                [false,'form']
                            ],
                            target: 'new',
                            context : mycontext,
                        });
      }
```

and this is xml

```xml
   <record model="ir.ui.view" id="olims_ar_priority_confirm_wizard">
    <field name="name">Set Default Priority Wizard</field>
    <field name="model">olims.ar.priority.wizard</field>
    <field name="type">form</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form>
            <group>
                <templates>
                    <t t-set="priority" t-value="request.env.context['current_priority']"/>
                    <span><t t-esc="priority"/>  is set as default</span>
                </templates>
            </group>
            <footer>
                <button string="Cancel" special="cancel" class="oe_highlight"/>
                <button name="agent_exceed_limit" string="Request Manager to Approve Sale" type="object" class="oe_highlight" />
            </footer>
        </form>
    </field>
</record>
```

Comment: Create one method in py, call that in js and pass arguments in it.

Comment: not sure but try <t t-set="priority" t-value=${ctx['current_priority']}/>